# Is there a Chrome extension to set the window title

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I use the [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nightly-tester-tools/) extension in Firefox to set the title and I need something similar for Chrome.

Searching only brings Title Bar Tweaker but it lacks the feature set of the Firefox extension and is conceptually different

This how the UI of the Nightly Tester Tools extension looks in Firefox

[image: Firefox Customize Title Bar]

Are there any Chrome extensions that use some Chrome variables like this? The GUI isn't so important.

Comment: Why do you want to change window title?

Comment: It allows me to tell apart different Chrome windows and profiles

Comment: Different profiles have little profile pictures on their icons. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uf3o.png

Comment: @gronostaj .Thanks for the tip, however I am using named profiles in Firefox, and the addons allow some browser variables to be used. which include the Profile names. Little profile pictures won't help me much. And I have scripts which search and work on the windows with the correct titles. I am adding an image to the question to give an idea of what I mean

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the title of a tab, the following bookmarklet would do:

> javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML=prompt("Enter new Title");})()

Just click it and enter a new title.

Comment: But would it change the window title as well, and is it event driven, so it would be computed every time the tab changed?

Comment: It doesn't change the window title. For it to be executed at every page load would require making an extension or userscript. Not my area of expertise :(